# Using NestJS + Prisma to build/migrate db schema on EC2 host to RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, nestjs, amazon-rds, prisma

I am struggling with Prisma connection using this cmd to build/migrate db schema on the server running NestJS on EC2 to a MySQL RDS instance.

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name init

-> error:
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `****.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com`:3306
```

Looks like a trouble with security group of either EC2 or RDS.
I added EC2 IP (x.x.x.x/32) for MySQL/Aurora (port 3306) on Inbound rules of RDS.